# Log in and log out capture based on location in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, locationmanager, userlocation

I have worked on one application name time tracker. User can manually swipe in and swipe out manually by clicking the button.

Now I would like to make it as automatic based on the location detection. For that I am using `CLLocationManager` class.  It works fine sometimes and sometimes it gives wrong swipe details. I am using below code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
     locationManager.delegate = self;
     locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

     if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
         [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

      [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

     _latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
     _longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

     if([_latitude.text doubleValue] > 17.76890) &&  [_longitude.text doubleValue] > 78.34567) {

         if (isSwipeIn) {
             isSwipeIn = false;
             //necessary swipe out UI and logic
         } else {
             isSwipeIn = true;
             //necessary swipe in UI and logic
      }
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing lat-long, go for a range check like if your device is within few meter mark as swipe in otherwise swipe out.

You can check distance between two lat-long using following method in Objective-C

```
CLLocation *location; // Your Location to compare
CLLocation *currentLocation; // Your current location
double distance = [location distanceFromLocation:currentLocation]; // Returns distance in meters

// Now lets say you are within 5 meters mark Swipe In

if(distance <= 5)
     // Mark swipe IN
else 
     // Mark swipe OUT
```

I hope this will help you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this, you can get distance from target location and check it with `horizontalAccuracy` of current location.

The `delta` gives you the distance between current location and targeted location. If `delta` is less than (<) `horizontalAccuracy` than current location is in a circle with a radius of `horizontalAccuracy`.

If `delta` is greater than (>) `horizontalAccuracy` than current location is far away than your targeted location.

So now `CLLocationManager` delegate method will be looks like below:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    _latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    _longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitude: %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    // Create Location object for your target location. e.g. (17.76890,78.34567)
    CLLocation *targetLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:17.76890 longitude:78.34567];
    CLLocationDistance delta = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:targetLocation];

    if (delta > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {
        if (isSwipeIn) {
            isSwipeIn = false;
            //necessary swipe out UI and logic
        } else {
            isSwipeIn = true;
            //necessary swipe in UI and logic
        }
    }
}
```